# skimage's resize generates a border when resizing to larger image

Tags: python, image, resize, scikit-image

I have lots of gray scale images of different sizes, most of which have a white background. I need to re-size them all to a standard size. Some will need to be reduced in size, some will need to be increased in size. When I use skimage resize to reduce the size of the original image, all works nicely. When the size needs to be increased, I get this funny gray-ish border. How can prevent that from happening?

```
from skimage.transform import resize 
from skimage import data
import pylab as plt

image = imread('https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/data/lenagray.png?raw=true', as_grey=True)

#plot Lena
plt.imshow(image,cmap=cm.gray)

#replace top with white
image[:20]=255

#plot the top 30 pixels, all seems ok
plt.imshow(image[:30,:30],cmap=cm.gray)
```

[image]

```
#resize, increase the original size
image2 = resize(image, (200, 200))

#plot the top pixels, a grayish border appears
plt.imshow(image2[:60,:60],cmap=cm.gray)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though using mode='nearest' takes care of it.

```
image2 = resize(image, (200, 200),mode='nearest')
```

Comment: Any extrapolation mode other than constant-value zero should help.

Comment: For future reference, `mode='nearest'` seems to be no longer available. `mode='reflect'` might work in this context or as pointed by @Stefan van der Walt any mode other than "constant" should work.

Comment: The default mode is currently `reflect`.  Other options are `{'constant', 'edge', 'symmetric', 'wrap'}`.